# Replacing some part of string with Python

Tags: python, string

I have a SQL string, for example

```
SELECT * FROM benchmark WHERE xversion = 1.0
```

And actually, xversion is aliased variable, and self.alias has all the alias info something like

```
{'CompilationParameters_Family': 'chip_name', 
 'xversion': 'CompilationParameters_XilinxVersion', 'opt_param':  
  ....
 'chip_name': 'CompilationParameters_Family', 
 'CompilationParameters_Device': 'device'}
```

Using this alias, I should change the string into as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM benchmark WHERE CompilationParameters_XilinxVersion = 1.0
```

For this change, I came up with the following.

```
def processAliasString(self, sqlString):
    components = sqlString.split(' ')
    resList = []
    for comp in components:
        if comp in self.alias:
            resList.append(self.alias[comp])
        else:
            resList.append(comp)
    resString = " ".join(resList)
    return resString
```

But, I expect better code not using for loop. What do you think?

Comment: I can see one potential weakness in your code. Think about what happens if `self.alias` is say, like this: `{'SELECT': 'DROP', '*': 'TABLE', 'FROM': '', 'WHERE': ';--' }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could change your input string's format to make the replacements more clearly visible, e.g.

```
s = 'SELECT * FROM benchmark WHERE %(xversion)s = 1.0'
```

then `s % self.alias` would suffice (there are some other alternatives available depending on your favorite formatting syntax and Python level).

If the input string format is "nailed down", `re` can help because of the ease it offers to identify word boundaries (so you won't e.g. unexpectedly miss a replacement if an otherwise insignificant space is missing, for example after `xversion`).  Consider (with `s` having its original form, with substitutables mixed in haphazardly with non-substitutables):

```
import re
sre = re.compile('|'.join(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s) for s in self.alias))
def repl(mo):
    return self.alias[mo.group()]
news = sre.sub(repl, s)
```

These approaches are fast, since `%`-formatting and `re`s' `sub` are really well optimized for such tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful tip. Unfortunately, the user gives me SQL command, so to use your code, I should parse to know exactly which part of the string should be modified, which is practically impossible now.

Comment: @prosseek, you can, however, use the `re`-based code in the second part of my answer (without risks from missing insignificant spaces, as would be with a `.split()`-based approach).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
def processAliasString(self, sqlString):
    return ' '.join(self.alias.get(comp, comp) for comp in sqlString.split(' '))
```